# Which Shimano freehub body fits Campagnolo Calima?

Tags: shimano, hub, freehub, campagnolo

I have a Campagnolo Calima C17 wheel set with currently a Campagnolo freehub body (FH-BU015) on it.

Does anyone know which type of Shimano freehub body fits on this wheel hub? I searched but I cant seem to find an answer. Before I spend lots of money on a body that does not fit, I want to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

The search process should be like this: First, search the web for "campagnolo calima spare parts". The first hit should be a product page that has link to spare part catalog. Download and open the catalog. Search for the page with Calima.

The answer is FH-BU015X1.

Comment: To answer the question as posed by OP, no shimano freehub body is compatible with Campagnolo components.

Comment: @HAEM I think you may be interpreting the question as, does Shimano make a Hyperglide freehub body that goes on Campy wheels. The more relevant issue is that Campy does make Hyperglide freehub bodies for both Campagnolo and Fulcrum wheels (NB: they own Fulcrum, similar to Roval -> Specialized, Cadex -> Giant). Indeed, I don't think most hub manufacturers go and source their Hyperglide freehub bodies from Shimano, or their Campy FH bodies straight from Campy, or their XD drivers from SRAM. The companies making hubs will tend to make all 3 (or perhaps they omit Campy).

Comment: Yes, the phrase "Shimano freehub body" is a bit ambiguous, so I interpreted it as "Shimano compatible freehub body". You can post a separate answer for the other interpretation.

Comment: Nice to see Campy made the freehub swap easier.  A decade ago you also had to swap the axle.